# Create generic audio path for iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, filepath

Analogous to what `UIImage imageNamed` does to replace the filesystem path for my image files, I am looking for a method to create a generic path from my absolute audio path on my filesystem.

Can anyone please let me know what method can help with this? I've browsed through the documentation, especially Core Audio with no luck. Thank you!

Comment: Generic audio path to what?  An audio file included as a resource in your project?

Comment: @Marko Yes, so it does not have to reference my filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some answers in the NSBundle documentation.